# Subprocess Call Scrapy - not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, subprocess

I am trying to run a scrapy spider using subprocess call but it isn't accepting any arguments, it knows what scrapy is though. For example -

```
from subprocess import call
call(["scrapy"], shell=True)
```

Works just fine and gives the expected output -

```
Scrapy 1.1.1 - project: instagram

Usage:
  scrapy <command> [options] [args]

Available commands:
  bench         Run quick benchmark test
  check         Check spider contracts
  commands      
  crawl         Run a spider
  edit          Edit spider
  fetch         Fetch a URL using the Scrapy downloader
  genspider     Generate new spider using pre-defined templates
  list          List available spiders
  parse         Parse URL (using its spider) and print the results
  runspider     Run a self-contained spider (without creating a project)
  settings      Get settings values
  shell         Interactive scraping console
  startproject  Create new project
  version       Print Scrapy version
  view          Open URL in browser, as seen by Scrapy

Use "scrapy <command> -h" to see more info about a command
```

but then if I try something simple like

```
call(["scrapy version"], shell=True)
```

I get -

```
'"scrapy version"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So scrapy is obviously seen and Im sure its a simple fix, could anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: which python version are you using? also, is this happening inside a project or just in the command line? could you try just running this in the terminal `python -c 'from subprocess import call; call(["scrapy version"], shell=True)'`

Comment: python 3, figured it out though, posted an answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, you have to do

```
call(["scrapy", "version"], shell=True)
```

instead

Comment: How can we do same for fetch to fetch some url?? I tried call(["scrapy","fetch(url)"], shell=True). It did not work.